ZFS I/O error after rebooting
I have a dual boot system with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04.  The latter is a separate SSD from Windows, which is marked as Offline in Windows so that it can't be touched, and uses the ZFS filesystem.
Today I booted into Ubuntu after a very long time of not using it.  As a result when I went to access some stuff in Google I had been logged out, but I only have my Google passwords available under Windows, so I did a proper reboot and got my password.  However, when I tried to boot back into Linux I get this error:
Command: /sbin/zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -N 'rpool'
Message: cannot import 'rpool': I/O error
   Destroy and re-create the pool from a backup source
cachefile import failed, retrying
    Destroy and re-create the pool from a backup source
Error: 1
Failed to import pool 'rpool'.
Manually import the pool and exit.

I am at  a bit of a loss and thought that maybe the BIOS got confused and renumbered the SSD drives again (there are 4, all identical make, model, and size, so they can be hard to keep straight) but it seems to be using the right drive because bpool is being mounted.  It's not clear what else could have happened, as I did a proper reboot in both directions, so I don't see how anything could have been corrupted.
Update: I discovered that I had already created a Hyper-V VM on the drive which I had forgotten about and it is running in Windows 11.  I was able to ssh and look at the VM but then got disconnected and was unable to reconnect and had to restart and get the same message when I try to boot in the VM.  I feel like I need some kind of fsck for ZFS...
I tried zdb -e rpool -ul and found the oldest txg.  Then I tried importing with this tag to try to bypass the corruption:
zpool import -o readonly=on -f -FX -N -T <txg#> rpool`

However I get this error:
"cannot import 'rpool': one or more devices is currently unavailable"

I assume this is because the pool is in the "FAULTED" state, but I can't clear this with zpool clear rpool because it doesn't find the pool because I haven't imported it yet.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
